# How to upgrade SQL Server 2008 to 2012 with table partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, upgrade

My project is upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to 2012, but old version consisting table partition. is this feature will work same as in 2012 also ?

Comment: http://www.sherweb.com/blog/upgrade-sql-server-2008-express-to-sql-server-2012-express/

Comment: follow the above.. u should google for the answers if any thing make u trouble or stuck come with that query in the stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about [partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) that utilizes partition schemes and partition functions in Sql Server 2008, you're obviously using Enterprise Edition.  That functionality has been supported in all Enterprise releases since its inception in 2005.

As of Sql server 2016 SP1, that functionality is supported in ALL editions.

Generally speaking, anytime you are preparing to upgrade from one version of Sql Server to another (2008 -> 2012, etc.), it's prudent to run the [Upgrade Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256(v=sql.120).aspx) tool for the release you are targeting.

> Upgrade Advisor analyzes installed components from earlier versions of
>   SQL Server, and then generates a report that identifies issues to fix
>   either before or after you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Scott, i'm trying to install Upgrade Advisor from SQL Server 2012 Setup.. getting below error.. to run upgrade advisor for 2012 is it mandatory to install 2012 in system ?

Comment: Thanks Scott, i'm tyring to install SQL Server 2012 Upgrade Advisor from SQL Server 2012 setup but i'm getting error as "SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom was missing". i'm i install Sql Server 2012 before upgrade Advisor  ?

Comment: check this link for information about the scriptdom error - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/42a565bf-2562-4fbd-a327-1487b7c17fa4/sql-server-2012-upgrade-advisor-wont-install?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: it is highly advisable to install the upgrade advisor for the 'target' version you're going to (2012 in your case) and point it to the 'source' version you are migrating from (2008 in your case)

Comment: I'm trying to run advisor.. but it is not displaying any instances in drop down list...if i type 'MSSQLSERVER' i'm getting this error "SQL Server version: 11.00.6020 is not supported by this release of Upgrade Advisor, only SQL2005, SQL2008 or SQL2008 R2 is supported".. i have updated to SP3

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to run the Sql 2008 R2 upgrade advisor against a Sql 2012 server.  Make sure you download the upgrade advisor software for Sql 2012 and point it to your Sql 2008 instance